# Why don't I see errors from readline.set_completion_display_matches_hook?

Tags: python, error-handling, readline, error-suppression, python-cmd

Consider this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from cmd import Cmd
import readline

class mycmd(Cmd):
    def match_display_hook(self, substitution, matches, longest_match_length):
        someNonexistentMethod()
        print()
        for match in matches:
            print(match)
        print(self.prompt, readline.get_line_buffer(), sep='', end='', flush=True)

    def do_crash(self, s):
        someNonexistentMethod()

    def do_quit(self, s):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = mycmd()
    readline.set_completion_display_matches_hook(obj.match_display_hook)
    obj.cmdloop()
```

I expect to see `NameError: name 'someNonexistentMethod' is not defined` when I run that and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>. However, nothing actually seems to happen at all (the error does occur, so the other functions that would print the completion don't run; I just don't see the error). I do see the expected error when I run `crash`, so I know error handling works fine in the program overall, but is just broken inside of the `set_completion_display_matches_hook` callback. Why is this, and can I do something about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why?

I would guess that this is by design. According to [rlcompleter docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/rlcompleter.html):

> Any exception raised during the evaluation of the expression is caught, silenced and None is returned.

See the [rlcompleter source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/rlcompleter.py) for the rationale:

> - Exceptions raised by the completer function are *ignored* (and generally cause the completion to fail).  This is a feature -- since readline sets the tty device in raw (or cbreak) mode, printing a traceback wouldn't work well without some complicated hoopla to save, reset and restore the tty state.

### Workaround

As a workaround, for debugging, wrap your hook in a function that catches all exceptions (or write a function decorator), and use the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) to log your stack traces to a file:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="example.log", format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')

def broken_function():
    raise NameError("Hi, my name is Name Error")

def logging_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    result = None
    try:
        result = broken_function(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.exception(ex)
    return result

logging_wrapper()
```

This script runs successfully, and *example.log* contains both the log message and the stack trace:

```
2020-11-17 13:55:51,714 Hi, my name is Name Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/traal/python/./stacktrace.py", line 12, in logging_wrapper
    result = function_to_run()
  File "/Users/traal/python/./stacktrace.py", line 7, in broken_function
    raise NameError("Hi, my name is Name Error")
NameError: Hi, my name is Name Error
```

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

It looks as if `readline` C-Binding just ignores exceptions when calling the hook, when <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed.

---

I believe the root of the problem might be these lines (1033-1049) in the C-binding [readline.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b7047e59a40649d81061acf0044e74cfd426f064/Modules/readline.c)

```c
    r = PyObject_CallFunction(readlinestate_global->completion_display_matches_hook,
                              "NNi", sub, m, max_length);

    m=NULL;

    if (r == NULL ||
        (r != Py_None && PyLong_AsLong(r) == -1 && PyErr_Occurred())) {
        goto error;
    }
    Py_CLEAR(r);

    if (0) {
    error:
        PyErr_Clear();
        Py_XDECREF(m);
        Py_XDECREF(r);
    }
```

Where, if an error occurs, it is just cleared. Reference to [PyErr_Clear()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_Clear)

### Steps I used for debugging:

#### Check if the Exception is raised

I changed the function to:

```py
def match_display_hook(self, substitution, matches, longest_match_length):
    try:
        someNonexistentMethod()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

which then printed `name 'someNonexistentMethod' is not defined` as expected (and all the other, expected, outputs). Raising any other Exception here did not quit the command prompt.

#### Check if printing to `stderr` works

At last, I checked if one could print to `sys.stderr` by adding:

```py
def match_display_hook(self, substitution, matches, longest_match_length):
    print("foobar", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
```

which printed `foobar` as expected.